# Transaction Starvation in Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, ethereum-classic, gas-price, pending-transactions

A miner chooses a particular transaction on basis of its GAS price i.e. miner generally doesn't pick a transaction with a lower gas price if he has options of other transactions with more gas price. So, can there is a chance of transaction starvation?

Answer (score 1):

By transaction starvation, do you mean that some transactions will not get chosen because their gas price is too low? Yes, this is a feature of the Ethereum blockchain (and BTC, and other...). If your gas price is set too low, it will take a very long time to confirm the tx, perhaps never.